# Exploding on semicolon except HTML codes

Tags: php, arrays, special-characters, explode

I have a file which contains values like `200 &#8240;P;450 RG`. The values are seperated with an explode on the semicolon (`;`), so it should be `value 1: 200 &#8240;P`, `value 2: 450 RG`. Sadly, the HTML special characters are causing problems, because they also contain a semicolon.

Is there a way to ignore the HTML characters or to set the HTML characters to their true value (and set them back to HTML after explode)?

I tried [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) and [html entities decode](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and both neither seem to work on &# symbols

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first decode html entities and then explode also can you please show your code what you have tried?

Comment: Have you tried [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Comment: I tried htmlspecialchars_decode and html entities decode and neither seem to work on `&#` symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said, use [html_entity_decode](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) first.

Links: https://eval.in/163799

```
<?php

$decodedText = html_entity_decode("200 &#8240;P;450 RG");

$values = explode(';', $decodedText);

foreach($values as $key => $value) {
  echo "value {$key}: {$value}".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Will Output:**

```
value 0: 200 ‰P
value 1: 450 RG
```

Comment: This indeed fixed the problem, I had to add `UTF-8` : `(html_entity_decode("200 &#8240;P;450 RG", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");)` to make it work. Seems like I'm using an older version of PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should first convert your HTML entities back to encoded text. You should use the PHP `html-entity-decode` function for that.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php